# C2DM Mobile Registration Phase

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm

I am new to C2DM and would like to test.  I have a question about mobile registration phrase.  since we need to use Google mail account in order to get the registration ID from C2DM server, is it possible to use device UUID instead of gmail account?

please advise or correct me if I have any miss understanding.
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

no you must use the google mail account you used to register. So it kinda becomes your api key for C2DM. That email address is also used in contacting the google server when sending the actual notifications as a trust indicator between you and google.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a separate Gmail address, not your personal Gmail and also not your mobile UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier). You have to use this email address in two different locations. One is in your Android application and the other one in your third party server. This email ID is important in the registration process. Which means the mobile phone which runs our C2DM enable Android app with the C2DM server. The [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) explains very well about the mobile implementation side but less with the server implementation side :-(